# Ways of Converting/manipulating Arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

I'm running into problems trying modularize my code into functions.

I'm trying to work with 2 separate arrays of rng outcomes in a manner that requires me to convert the indexes whole values into single digit values,
then store them in an array. I've been using this as a method to populate my array, but would prefer it to be a function that I can call on any array and return it w/ a new adjusted outcome.:

```
var outcome1 = rng(); var outcome2 = rng();
function rng() {
Array.from({length: 2}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 9));
}

values = [];
// Intended Digitize function for Arrays
while(outcome1 > 0) {
  values[values.length] = outcome1 % 10;
  outcome1 = parseInt(outcome1 / 10);
  values.reverse();
}
```

If needed I'll need to be able to replace some of those digits, and then concat that array of single value digits into a Number value (based on how many digits the outcome may contain(after numberAdjust)). Since the values can produce a 0 from rng(intended), the function needs to be able to see if the outcome has a value of 0 in it, and if so replace that value, while also setting a boolean that'll serve as a flag for different adjustments later.

```
// numberAdjust function
// regex to remove 0 giving outcome new .length /unsure if needs own func
// outcome1.replace(/[0]/g); ??
(if outcome1.toString().length <= 1 && outcome2.toString().length <= 1) {
  outcome00 = true;
  outcome1.push(1);
  outcome2.push(1);
} else if (outcome1.toString().length <=1) {
  outcome0_ = true;
  outcome1.push(1);
} else if (outcome2.toString().length <=1) {
  outcome_0 = true;
  outcome2.push(1);
} else {
  outcome = true; }
```

Once the number value has been recreated with its new pushed values (or not), it then needs to be able to convert the adjustedOutcomes back into an array single digit values (digitize function) incase any of digit values may need be manipulated again (reason for booleans).
Once (/if any) manipulation is done the digitized array needs to be converted back into a Number.

```
function numberize(...args) {
  args = Number(args.join(''));
  return args;
}
```

This numberize function needs to be able to convert a digitzed array back into a number, and it also needs to be able to take in multiple arrays, and concat both of those arrays into a Number as well.

Basically I just need to be able to freely turn and store either 1 or 2 arrays into an array of single digit values. Add/replace values in those arrays based on length (if rng outcome provides a 0), and be able to convert the digitized arrays back into whole Numbers.

I appreciate any advice given, thank you :)